# How to read several web pages without closing url link

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests-html

I use Python 3.7 with Spyder in Anaconda. I don't have a lot of experience with Python so I might use the wrong technical terms in my problem description.

I use the requests library to read process data of a list of part numbers, from a database with a web page interface. I use the following code. I found most of it on StackOverflow.

```
# Libraries
import requests
import pandas as pd
import lxml.html as LH

# Get link for part results from hyperlink list
for link in hyperlink_list:
    # Add part number to database link
    process_url = database_link + link
    html = requests.get(process_url).content
    # Read data to dataframe
    df_list = pd.read_html(html)
```

The for loop fetches the link for the next part number from the hyperlink list and then modifies the process_url to extract the data for that part number. The code above works well except that it takes more than twice as long (2.2 seconds) as my vba code that does the same. It looks like it opens and closes the link for every part number. Is there any way to open the url link and read many different web pages before closing the link.

I'm making the assumption that it opens and closes the link for every part based on the fact that I had the same time delay when I used Excel vba code that opened and closed internet explorer for every data read. When I changed the vba code to keep explorer open and read all the web pages, it took less than a second.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to reduce the time by 0.5 seconds by removing  requests.get(process_url).content
and using pandas to directly read the data with  df_list = pd.read_html(process_url). It now takes around 1.7 seconds to read the 400 rows of data in the table for each part. This adds up to a good time saving when I have to read thousands of tables but is still slower than the vba script. Below is my new code

```
import pandas as pd
# Get link for part results from hyperlink list
for link in hyperlink_list:
   # Add part number to database link
   process_url = database_link + link
   df_list = pd.read_html(process_url)
   df = df_list[-1]
```